# ng-hide logic not working correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ng-hide

I working on an Ionic app and I'm having some trouble with the ng-hide directive. I'm trying to show or hide a button, based on whether the user has already registered or not.

The button:

```
<button class="button button-clear button-block button-positive button-register"
          ui-sref="register" ng-hide="register.haveRegistered">
            Register
          </button>
```

After a user registers a property gets set on the local storage indicated that they did so (this is done via another controller):

```
$storage.set("registrationRequested", true);
```

When the user lands on the login screen - the screen containing the button I would like to hide - the following controller comes into play and does the following:

```
 $scope.register = {
      'haveRegistered' : false
    };
    $scope.register.haveRegistered = $storage.get("registrationRequested", false)
```

Initially the button is shown, and that's great, but after the user registers and I write the indicator to the local storage, and then **go back to the login page** via `$state.go('login');` ng-hide doesn't seem to work. Any tips?

Comment: Is your button under same controller as `$scope.register` is in?

Comment: Yes it is, the loginController

Comment: I'm wondering if this has something to do with the loginController not being executed again when returning back to it's view via $state.go()

Answer (score 0):

Try reloading like this -

```
$state.go('login', { }, { reload: true });
```

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work either. I've confirmed now it's because the loginController doesn't run. Very weird..